# PHP - Convert binary to image and store it on server

Tags: php, image, file

Hello I have PHP script to retrieve image and file name. I have got image and file name successfully. There is no problem about that. And after converting to the binary I want to save it as image on my server. But I am unable to save that image. Here is my PHP script.

```
<?php

    // Get image string posted from Android App
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    // Get file name posted from Android App
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
    // Decode Image
    $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    // Images will be saved under 'www/imgupload/uplodedimages' folder
    $file = fopen('uploadedimages/'.$filename, 'wb');
    // Create File
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory\n';

?>
```

Comment: do you have error reporting turned on? could this be a permissions issue ?

Comment: no there is no any permission issue. I have tested $binary and $filename. It works.

Comment: Is there any error message that you are getting ?

Comment: No...I am getting 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory'

Comment: that is because your code will display that message irrespective of what happens.

Comment: please I need solution... :(

Comment: It does not work like that here. You need to put in some work on your side. Make sure error reporting is turned on and see if you are getting any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple code which I use to store images on my webserver, It doesn't convert images to binary, but it does the job of storing images onto the server.

You should create a `uploads` folder and give full permissions such as `777` to it.

```
<?php
echo $_FILES['image']['name'] . '<br/>';


//ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
//ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
//ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
//ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);


$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

try {
    //throw exception if can't move the file
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        throw new Exception('Could not move file');
    }

    echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['image']['name']) .
    " has been uploaded";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('File did not upload: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

HTML which links to the php file (for your reference)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="fileUpload.php" method="POST">            
            Select a file<input name="image" type="file" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```